# Make text selection treat adjacent elements as separate words

Tags: html, css

Normally, the browser's text selection seems to combine words if they are separated by any whitespace in the HTML. (`<span/> <span/>` will be separate, while `<span/><span/>` will be combined.)

However, I want my elements to have a specific amount of whitespace between them, rather than a space which is dependent on the font choice / text layout.

When there is whitespace separating the elements, the gap between them is **more** than I specify (because a space is also rendered). When the elements abut, the gap is the right size, but double-clicking one word highlights both words, and they'll be copied as if they were a single word (FooBar in this example).

[image]

Is there a way to make text selection treat these as **separate words** while ensuring there's no extra whitespace to interfere with the spacing I specified in CSS? (Edit: ideally they would also be separate words when copied to the clipboard.)

```css
.pad {
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Foo</span>
  <span>Bar</span>
  (separate because there's whitespace)
</div>

<div>
  <span>Foo</span><span>Bar</span>
  (combined because there's no whitespace)
</div>

<div>
  <span>Foo</span>
  <span class="pad">Bar</span>
  (separate words, but more space than I specified)
</div>

<div>
  <span>Foo</span><span class="pad">Bar</span>
  (can I make text selection treat these as separate words?)
</div>
```

Comment: Perhaps this: https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/658/removing-whitespaces-between-inline-block-elements-with-css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a separation like [zero-width space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space):

```css
.pad {
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Foo</span>
  <span>Bar</span>
  (separate because there's whitespace)
</div>

<div>
  <span>Foo</span><span>Bar</span>
  (combined because there's no whitespace)
</div>

<div>
  <span>Foo</span>
  <span class="pad">Bar</span>
  (separate words, but more space than I specified)
</div>

<div>
  <span>Foo</span>&#8203;<span class="pad">Bar</span>
  (can I make text selection treat these as separate words?)
</div>
```

Also like below (edit the snippet to see the invisible character)

```css
.pad {
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Foo</span>
  <span>Bar</span>
  (separate because there's whitespace)
</div>

<div>
  <span>Foo</span><span>Bar</span>
  (combined because there's no whitespace)
</div>

<div>
  <span>Foo</span>
  <span class="pad">Bar</span>
  (separate words, but more space than I specified)
</div>

<div>
  <span>Foo</span>​<span class="pad">Bar</span>
  (can I make text selection treat these as separate words?)
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a good idea! But now when I select both words and copy, I get "Foo​Bar" which looks like there's no space because there's a zero-width space. Is there a way I could make it so that it gets copied as a regular space?

Comment: @jtbandes it's not because there is a zero-width space but because the only space is the one applied with the padding and when you copy the text you don't copy the style. If you want be able to keep the space when you copy you are obliged to have a real space so you can have a space styled to be invisible like this: https://jsfiddle.net/qcdo5zwj/

Answer (score -1):

why not use margin?

example:

```
<span style="margin-right:5px">Foo</span>
<span>Bar</span>
```

result:

```
Foo   Bar
```

Comment: The space between them won't be exactly 5px if there's also whitespace — that's the problem I'm trying to solve.